# What is convenient way of parsing rfc3339 in python?

Tags: python, rfc3339

I found several ways of doing it and found a lot of answers/articles and all of them offer different ways:

a) Using [`dateutil.parser.isoparse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse). This package is mentioned in `datetime` documentation as package for parsing `ISO 8601` format and I guess, it would have been the answer to my question, but I guess there is possibility of getting case that suits `rfc3339` and not `ISO 8601`.

b) Using `pyrfc3339` is also third-party project which seems fine and easy to use, but I didn't find it to be mentioned much

c) A lot of other packages

1. So what is convenient way of parsing rfc3339?
2. Are there some hidden problems in options above?

Comment: Negative timezones are part of ISO 8601.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure [datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) wouldn't work for your use case(s)?